# Flash resemblance on C#

Tags: c#, flash

I'm having a problem converting a Flash game to C#.
In Flash I would use this syntax:

```
public function doMove()
{
    eaze(this).to(actionTime, {x:destX, y:destY}).onComplete(completeMove);
}
public function completeMove()
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("checkMatch"));
    //this will run doCheckMatch on other class
}
```

but then I thought it should just be running the

```
public void doMove()
{
    completeMove();
}
private void completeMove()
{
    container.doCheckMatch(this);
    //this will run doCheckMatch on other class
}
```

My Question is, is that the same or not?
If not, what should I do in C# to resemble the same function in Flash?
One more thing though. I don't need any animation movement in C#, which Flash has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the same, because in flash you dispatch event, so `completeMove` will be done **after** `doMove` finished. In C# you call `completeMove()`, so it will be done **inside** 'doMove'. The reason is that your code in C# is thread blocking, in actionscript is asynchronous.

Comment: so, if i just reverse the condition it could be the same?

Comment: which condition you would like to reverse?

Comment: sorry, its seems that i misunderstand your answer. You saying that `doMove` will be done after `completeMove` done? am I correct?

Comment: you said in flash, `completeMove` will start after `doMove` or will be done? I kinda confused now. if its will be done whats the difference from that statement?

Comment: in flash you invoke event, so the function will be executed when event will be handled. It is almost always after function finish, but it doesn't have to be exactly after. Something between can happened, for example handling of other event, redrawing UI, etc. In C# code you invoke this function, so it will be done INSIDE, so nothing can happen in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,@Garath. I understand the concept now, but still, I didn't have any idea how i should do on C#...

Comment: It will work, just "way how it works" is different. Search for asynchronous programming, delegates, event handles, etc. , to have same effect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28010/discussion-between-diom-and-garath)